# How to write a real self-contained Django app?

Tags: django

They say Django apps should be self-contained.
I find it hard to implement.

My website has 3 apps. All have their own `static` and `templates` folders.
But — like many other sites — they share same front-end design.

The problem is, I have a very small form at the footer of each page to sign up for my newsletter. First, I have to define the database model in one of apps, which means the other two rely on that one. Second, the view to update the database should be defined in an app — naturally, the same app that defines the model — which again means the other two have to call that view.

So, `app1` provides the model and view, `app2` and `app3` use them; so they are not self-contained.

Isn't this against the philosophy?